# Gradle problem after installing Android Studio 2020.3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBNjD.png)

I got an old project, and we always add somethings...But after installing last version of A.S. i just get this error. Any idea?

Comment: update your build tools in build.gradle(project) and gradle in gradle-wrapper

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so in the image, you can see there is an option that says

> update Gradle wrapper...
> Click that and upgrade your project, this should solve your error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when i upgrade gradle to higher one, there is another errors i get. But i solved this from Settings -> Debugger -> I changed JVM to oldest one.

Comment: @NotRxlly You can answer your own question and mark it as an answer so that this question is closed.